# Hide and Show Looped Components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, css-transitions

I have a series of questions for a sign-up flow I am building. Currently, I am looping through each components and displaying them all on one page. My questions are, **How do I show only one at a time? How can I include a slide left transition/animation when each slide hides/shows?** I would like each question to display individually then once the user clicks next, it hides the first question and displays the second. I am a bit newer to React so I apologize if this is a basic question but I cannot figure it out.

Below are breakouts of my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Q1Name from './questions/Q1Name';
import Q2Birthday from './questions/Q2Birthday';
import Q3City from './questions/Q3City';
import Q4YouReady from './questions/Q4YouReady';
import Q5Setting from './questions/Q5Setting';
import Q6Length from './questions/Q6Length';
import Q7Email from './questions/Q7Email';


class SignUpPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const components = [Q1Name, Q2Birthday, Q3City, Q5Setting, Q6Length, Q7Email];
        const componentsToRender = components.map((Component, i) => (
            <Component key={i} />
        ));

        return (
            <div className = "container-fluid">
                <div className = "question-box">
                    {componentsToRender}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SignUpPage;
```

This is an example component - they are all slightly different so I am showing the two primary types:

the first only has a single "next button"

```
import React from 'react';

class Q2Birthday extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="questions">
                <h1 id="question-h1">When is your birthday?</h1>
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="date" className="form-control custom-form" id="birthdayInput" aria-describedby="birthday" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-custom btn-lg">Next Question!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Q2Birthday;
```

the second has 3 button options the user can select from

```
import React from 'react';

class Q6Length extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="questions">
                <h1 id="question-h1">How long would you like your trip to be?</h1>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-custom-select btn-lg">Just a weekend!</button>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-custom-select btn-lg">A full week!</button>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-custom-select btn-lg">I'm flexible!</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Q6Length;
```

I also want to add in a slide left transition for the "questions" div within the question-box class. I have been reading up on react-transition-group but I am a bit confused on how to implement it. Also, with this application, I do not need to store the values of the form data.

Comment: Why don't you play with CSS? just add/remove classes for showing/hiding the elements on component's next/prev buttons

Comment: I have been playing with the css part but I am having a hard time getting them to show and hide with the loop. Right now everything is showing at one time so I am trying to figure out how to make each element only show after the next button on the previous has been clicked.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I show only one at a time?

Given that you want to do a slide transition between them, you need at least the one being left behind and the next one to show to be in the DOM at switchover time. When not switching it's possible to have only the current one in the DOM. But simplest would probably be to always have all of them in the DOM, just with the previous/next ones out of the left/right sides of the viewport.

So to answer the question of how to show just one at a time, one way would be to translate all "old" ones left by 100% of the container width, leave the current one be, and translate all "next" ones right by 100%.

Styles for that might look like this:

```
const oldStyle = {
  position: 'absolute',
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  transform: 'translate(-100%)',
};
const currentStyle = {
  position: 'relative',
  transform: 'translate(0)',
};
const nextStyle = {
  position: 'absolute',
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  transform: 'translate(100%)',
};
```

Depending on where this is on your page, you might need some additional styles to hide the overflowing next/previous slides. Look up the `overflow` property. You may also need to fix heights or widths of the container -- look into this if you find the non-current slides have an unexpected (such as zero) height or width.

To apply the appropriate styles to each panel, you'll need to know which is which.

I'd suggest keeping track of the current slide index in your parent component's state. Say you have this in `this.state.currentSlide`. With that, you can choose the slide styles like this:

```
const componentsToRender = components.map((Component, i) => (
  <Component key={i} style={i < this.state.currentSlide ? oldStyle : i === this.state.currentSlide ? currentStyle : nextStyle} />
));
```

In order for that `style` prop to pass through to your slides, you'd need to tweak the slides a little. The simplest way would just be to explicitly pass that one through:

```
<div className="questions" style={this.props.style}>
```

But how do we set the current slide in state, and keep it up to date? Well, in the simplest case, you need to initialize it at zero. Your slide components will need to tell the parent when they've finished. And you'll need to notice that, and update the state.

```
class SignUpPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Set initial state
    this.state = {
      currentSlide: 0,
    };
  }

  // Handle notification from a child slide that we should move to the next
  nextSlide() {
    this.setState({
      currentSlide: this.state.currentSlide + 1,
    });
  }

  render() {
    ...
    const componentsToRender = components.map((Component, i) => (
      <Component key={i} style={this.props.style} onNext={this.nextSlide.bind(this)} />
    ));
```

The child components then need to call this method which has been passed in when they're finished:

```
class Q2Birthday extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit(event) {
    // Don't perform an actual form submission
    event.preventDefault();

    // Notify the parent
    this.props.onNext();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="questions" style={this.props.style}>
        <h1 id="question-h1">When is your birthday?</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          ...
```

> How can I include a slide left transition/animation when each slide hides/shows?

With the above styles, it might be as simple as setting the following style for each of the slides:

```
transition: transform 0.5s;
```